# JAVA Swing: Can't append a text to a TextArea

Tags: java, swing

I simply try to append a text to a text area if I press a button. I separated it, so the textArea has made in a different class named TextPanel. The interesting part is that I also print out the text to the console if I press that button and it works on the console, just can't append it to my textArea...
Here is my code:

Toolbar.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Toolbar extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private JButton helloButton;
    private JButton goodbyeButton;
    private TextPanel textPanel;

    public Toolbar() {

        helloButton = new JButton("Hello!");
        goodbyeButton = new JButton("Goodbye!");
        textPanel = new TextPanel();

        helloButton.addActionListener(this);
        goodbyeButton.addActionListener(this);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        add(helloButton);
        add(goodbyeButton);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JButton clicked = (JButton)e.getSource();

        if (clicked == helloButton) {
            textPanel.appendText("Hello!\n");
            System.out.println("Hello!\n");
        }
        else if (clicked == goodbyeButton) {
            textPanel.appendText("Goodbye!\n");
            System.out.println("Goodbye!\n");
        }
    }
    /*
    public void setTextPanel(TextPanel textPanel) {
        this.textPanel = textPanel;
    }
    */
}
```

TextPanel.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TextPanel extends JPanel{

    private JTextArea textArea;

    public TextPanel() {

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void appendText(String text) {
        textArea.append(text);
    }
}
```

MainFrame.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

    private JButton btn;
    private TextPanel textPanel;
    private Toolbar toolbar; 

    public MainFrame() {

        super("My First JAVA Swing Window");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        textPanel = new TextPanel();
        toolbar = new Toolbar();

        add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        setSize(600,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

App.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the textPanel object with `add(textPanel);`

---

**Extended answer due to the addition of the Main class code:**.
Remove `textPanel = new TextPanel()` from your Toolbar class, uncomment the `setTextPanel` method and call `toolbar.setTextPanel(textPanel)` just after you create the toolbar with `toolbar = new Toolbar()`.
The issue is that you're creating two instances of textPanel, and only modifying the one that you haven't added to the frame.

Comment: @FrigyesVass in that case, maybe the problem is that you're making two different text panels and calling `appendText` on the one that you haven't added to the frame?

Comment: Now it works! Thanks! Actually I copied the setTextPanel method from a tutorial and it looks like its made just to solve this problem, but I dont really understand how it solves it... Can you explain it to me?

Comment: No problem, glad it works! Every time you run `new TextPanel()` it creates a new _instance_ of a class. When you made two instances, they are separate from each other, so calling `textAppend` on one does not affect the other. When you create an instance in one class, if you want to change it in another class you have to pass it between classes as a parameter of a method - this is what `setTextPanel` does. What you're doing is telling the `Toolbar` class to use the same instance that you created in `MainFrame`, so changes you make will affect it in both classes as its the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set an initial size to the `JTextArea`?

You can try with [setRows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setRows(int)) and [setColumns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setColumns(int))

```
public TextPanel() {

    textArea = new JTextArea();

    textArea.setRows(10);
    textArea.setColumns(10);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```